# TeamCity Build - show which TFS Work Items have been fixed

Tags: tfs, build, teamcity, tfs-workitem

we use TFS as source control system.
When we check in, we provide a comment and relate to a work item.

We use TeamCity for automated builds.
Teamcity nicely shows us the ceck-in comments, but the test manager would like to see the Work Items related to the check-ins in the TeamCity build information.

Is this possible? How?

Kind regards,
Ugly Papa Ramone

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin avaialable from jet brains to do this.
http://teamcity.jetbrains.com/project.html;jsessionid=6B41F83740F0A6F1F6C3056661013EA8?projectId=project50&tab=projectOverview

James

Comment: I installed the plugin. 
It shows me the TFS ChangeSet ids, comments and changed files. However, I do not find any TFS WorkItem ids or details.
I would like to see the Id, Description and Status of the related TFS WorkItems. It should be possible, because from the commandline I can obtain the related WorkItem ID using TFSWrapper. It seems the tfsissuetracker plugin does not send the right commands or arguments to TFSWrapper (e.g. FindMentionsByChangeset command). Can this be monitored?

Comment: Do I need to install TfsWrapper in the path? Should I see a TFSWrapper process running in -mode=client ? Should I add an Issue Tracker of type TFS (which I do not see)?

Comment: Does this plugin use the credentials provided in the Version Control configuration of the build?